# Proper format of fstore for fcntl under Python

Tags: python, fcntl

I want to preallocate storage for files using python. With fcntl, I can preallocate storage under C:

```
  int fd = myFileHandle;
  fstore_t store = {F_ALLOCATECONTIG, F_PEOFPOSMODE, 0, aLength};
  int ret = fcntl(fd, F_PREALLOCATE, &store);
    if(-1 == ret){
    store.fst_flags = F_ALLOCATEALL;
    ret = fcntl(fd, F_PREALLOCATE, &store);
    if (-1 == ret)
      return false;
```

When I try to perform something similar under Python, I get an error 22:

```
    F_ALLOCATECONTIG = 2
    F_PEOFPOSMODE = 3
    F_PREALLOCATE = 42

    f = open(source, 'r')
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    size = f.tell()
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

    my_fstore = struct.pack('lllll', F_ALLOCATECONTIG, F_PEOFPOSMODE, 0, size, 0)
    d = open(destination, 'w')
    fcntl.fcntl(d.fileno(), F_PREALLOCATE, my_fstore)
```

I am passing a struct call my_fstore which should be the same as the c struct that the fcntl call requires when performing an F_PREALLOCATE.

```
/*  fstore_t type used by F_DEALLOCATE and F_PREALLOCATE commands */

typedef struct fstore {
    unsigned int fst_flags; /* IN: flags word */
    int     fst_posmode;    /* IN: indicates use of offset field */
    off_t   fst_offset; /* IN: start of the region */
    off_t   fst_length; /* IN: size of the region */
    off_t   fst_bytesalloc; /* OUT: number of bytes allocated */
} fstore_t;
```

All of the elements in the structure should be 64 bit lengths, hence the 'l' formatter in the python struct. Any recommendations on what I could do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can do this easily using the python fallocate library which imports the fallocate call on linux and osx:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fallocate/1.6.1

That being said, I was able to accomplish this using the following fcntl configuration on OSX:

```
F_ALLOCATECONTIG = 2
F_PEOFPOSMODE = 3
F_PREALLOCATE = 42            
f = open(source, 'r')

f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = f.tell()
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

d = open(destination, 'w')

params = struct.pack('Iiqq', F_ALLOCATECONTIG, F_PEOFPOSMODE, 0, size)
fcntl.fcntl(d.fileno(), F_PREALLOCATE, params)
```